# Related List Files vs Notes & Attachments

Tags: attachment, related-list, files

users want me to add a related list to a custom object to allow you to add attachments.
What is the difference between the "Files" and "Notes & Attachments" related list?

Comment: you could refer https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_files_differences.htm&type=5

Comment: there is no information about the differences between the related lists at link

Comment: The related lists are different because they are different objects.  You can do a quick web search to find the differences between the Files object and the Attachments object.